# Delete dropdown choice dynamically in Django

Tags: python, django

I need to hide a choice from a dropdown when a user is not authenticated.

```
class JobPostingListView(ListView):
    form_class = JobPostingSearchForm
    model = JobPosting
    template_name = 'recruiters/job_posting_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):

        form = self.form = self.form_class(self.request.GET)

    ......


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        context_data = super(JobPostingListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            del self.form.fields['date_posted'].choices[1]

        #Ok, It shows all except choice one
        print self.form.fields['date_posted'].choices 

        #It doesn't work here because it shows all the choices 
        print self.form                               

        context_data.update({
            'form': self.form                         
        })

        return context_data
```

Note: The code is in the view because I don't have access to `is_authenticated` in the form.

The form shows all the choices and **I want to hide the choice one**.

Comment: instead of using `is False`, use `not`. This is more preferred. `    if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():` Also question is not clear. Is this not working? (which is what I suspect)

Comment: also, how is `self.form` assigned. Is it the class or an instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A colleague helped me with that.

1. Inside `get_queryset` function.
2. Call `form.fields['date_posted'].widget.choices.pop(1)` in order to show the form without the choice one.
3. Call `form.fields['date_posted'].choices.pop(1)` to avoid the user modify the html and send a not valid choice in this case.

   ```
   class JobPostingListView(ListView):
       form_class = JobPostingSearchForm
       model = JobPosting
       template_name = 'recruiters/job_posting_list.html'

       def get_queryset(self):

           form = self.form = self.form_class(self.request.GET)
           if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():
               form.fields['date_posted'].choices.pop(1)
               form.fields['date_posted'].widget.choices.pop(1)
       ...
   ```